# How to differentiate ajax result in HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns a result in HTML. If the request is good, it returns a  list of contacts in HTML; otherwise it should return validation errors. Both scenarios return HTML.

The problem is this: If the requests to the server is successful, I have no way to tell if the result is validation errors or the list of contacts. I need to know so I can manipulate my HTML accordingly:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            [snip]
            success: function(response) {
                 // here I need to tell if there was a validation error
                 // or the request succeeded
            }
```

For example, HTML for a good request might look like...

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>@contact-name</td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
```

While a bad request will look like...

```
<ul>
    <li>Please fix some error</li>
</ul>
```

I display the results in different locations, hence the need to distinguish between possible results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to move to JSON, and you don't want to use different status codes, given your markup you can differentiate based on the tag name of the first element:

```
success: function(response) {
    var elements = $(response);
    if (elements[0].tagName.toUpperCase() === "UL") {
        // ...bad response...
    }
    else {
        // ...good response...
    }

    // Display it either way (in our case, we just append, but you'll probably
    // put them in different places)
    elements.appendTo(document.body);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ikupuq)

Or for that matter, include a dummy element at the outset that you always remove, which includes the result (e.g., `<div class='good'></div>` vs. `<div class='bad'></div>`).

Answer (score 2):

You could encode your response in json and send with a code that tells if the request was successful or not.

Comment: I could, but I was hoping to avoid JSON because it's a pain in the rear-side to do that in my particular situation.

Comment: Another solution would be to search your HTML response for a certain keyword, such as "error": response.indexOf('error') !== -1

Comment: This is just a though, but perhaps you could send back your response with a custom http header, something like "ajax-request-success: 1" or similar.

Comment: You could also make the first let's say div in your response contain the error code and parse it using jquery, or return your response in xml.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought:

If you return a JSON object with a success flag, and your HTML content, you can know where to put the HTML.

The JSON would look something like this:

```
{
  success: true,
  html: "<ul><li>Html here</li></ul>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct semantic way to do this would be with HTTP headers.  If the error is that a contact isn't found, issue a 404 Not Found status code.  This will fire the `error` handler rather than the `success` handler, so you can tell the difference and run different code.

Comment: Well, it's sort of a validation error, so it's not exactly a 404... which makes me a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the server return a custom 2xx status code with the nature of the problem in the status text.

Since a validation response is a successful response, you want to use a 200-series code and using a custom status code lets you distinguish that type of response from all other potential responses.